# 1264 Out of range value for column for datetime column value

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMN_NAME(DATETIME DATATYPE)=str_to_date('2014-08-07 19:22:21','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

it gives

> 1264 Out of range value for column COLUMN_NAME

Comment: Why are you trying to rename a column to be a datetime value? that's utterly insane? ``select `2014-08-07 19:22:21` from yourtable ...`` is going to confuse the hell out of everyone else who has to maintain this code down the road.

Comment: @MarcB: I get the distinct impression that the OP is trying to do something in an unfortunately denormalized fashion.  For example, one could attempt to store client IDs and some parameter about the across time, by having each time point be a column rather than a properly normalized set of <client,time,value> triplets.

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to assign a date time as a column name.  I think the OP is simply trying to insert a "string" timestamp into a date time field.  The tableName and column_Name were just place holders where the (datetime datatype) defined the column data type. and somehow the casting to datetime isn't working as expected.

Comment: Do I get correctly that `(DATETIME DATATYPE)` is just an explanation that `COLUMN_NAME` has type `DATETIME` and is not an actual part of the query?

Comment: @MarcB I don’t get what you say. Renaming a column? That is achieved via `ALTER TABLE` in MySQL. What am I missing?

Comment: I can generate this warning only with invalid dates like '2014-06-31', not with the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use simple update

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMN_NAME='2014-08-07 19:22:21';
```

?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Lal The OP is very bad, the published code doesn't produce the error message in the post, but this is an answer.

Comment: @VMai I guess that this is a partial answer, but 1) nobody can be sure about that, because the question is crappy (does not state its intention), and 2) the answer is crappy, because it does not explain anything. Date and time given in this format form a valid DATETIME value, no conversion is needed. If you use other format of date and time, only then you need the STR_TO_DATE function.